# What's the difference between Unpooled and UnpooledByteBufAllocator?

Tags: netty

It seems netty 4.0.24.final has both `Unpooled` and `UnpooledByteBufAllocator` can be used to allocate unpooled buffers. So why 2? When to use which?

### ADD 1

I dig a bit into the source code of Netty 4.0.24.Final. Here's my findings so far.

It's Netty's philosophy to expose broad range of functionality via a small number of interfaces/abstract classes. So I started with the abstract class `ByteBuf`.

The type hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

So `ByteBuf` can be categorized as `Pooled || Unpooled` or `Direct || Heap`.

The `Unpooled` class is implemented like this:

[image]

The `ALLOC` is used in `Unpooled` to allocate buffers.

So I think `Unpooled` and `UnpooledByteBufferAllocator` are closely related.

Some questions still pending:

- Why the designer of netty doesn't introduce a `UnpooledByteBuf<T>` in the hierarchy just like the `PooledByteBuf<T>`? This will make the type hierarchy more symmetric.
- It seems `Unpooled` kind of wraps the `UnpooledByteBufAllocator`, so why need both?

Comment: @trustin A more detailed explanation of Netty 4 buffer management will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`PooledByteBuf<T>` is an abstract parent that holds most of the pooling logic which is common to the Direct, UnsafeDirect and Heap implementations. The unpooled versions don't have that common logic to be shared. That's where the asymmetry probably comes from.

Generally speaking, buffer allocators are not supposed to be instantiated directly. They can be set as a `ChannelOption` and throughout the lifecycle of your channel, whenever you call `channel.alloc()`, the instance set at the channel construction time will be returned. You should be mostly using that one. Whether it will be pooled/unpooled, direct safe/unsafe or heap-based depends on Netty's defaults, your configuration and the platform you're running in.

`Unpooled` is the preferred way, if you can't or don't want to call `channel.alloc()`, because it will release you from the burden of checking platform-dependent things like the the presence of `Unsafe` when using a `wrappedBuffer()`. Having said that, at the end of the day it's indeed an utility class and you could probably do all that *by hand*, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Unpooled is just a static helper class that can be used to create unpooled bytebufer instances...

Comment: The maintainers should probably rename that to UnpooledUtils or something